# How can I set up fully anonymous access to a Samba share?

Tags: samba, file-sharing

```
guest account = nobody 
guest only = yes 
guest ok  = yes 
map to guest = bad user
```

This is a crutch to access shared folder with a random name which I type. I hate this method.

I am looking for solution to access without a prompt dialog coming up every time, even for a random name.